# How to search Host Groups in Zabbix API

Tags: api, zabbix

I want to list all Host Groups that match some search criteria.

I've tried that:

```
data = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0",                
         "method": "hostgroup.get",       
         "params": {                      
             "output": "extend",          
              "search": {                 
                 "name": [                
                     "' + group_name + '"
                 ]                        
            },                            
         },                               
         "id":' + str(msg_id) + ',        
         "auth": "' + auth + '"           
       }'
```

But that is not a correct syntax.

I also tried this:

```
data = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0",                
     "method": "hostgroup.get",       
     "params": {                      
         "output": "extend",          
          "filter": {                 
             "name": [                
                 "' + group_name + '"
             ]                        
        },                            
     },                               
     "id":' + str(msg_id) + ',        
     "auth": "' + auth + '"           
   }'
```

This one works, but it only matches exactly the group name. And, so, it always returns 1 or 0 matches.

I tried adding the `"options":"searchWildcardsEnabled"` option in this last query, but it didn't make a difference in the result (i.e. it didn't produce multiple groups as output).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the correct way. I'll post it here in case anyone else needs it later.

```
data = '{"jsonrpc": "2.0",                
     "method": "hostgroup.get",       
     "params": {                      
         "output": "extend",          
          "search": {                 
             "name": [                
                 "' + group_name + '"
             ]                        
        }                             
     },                               
     "id":' + str(msg_id) + ',        
     "auth": "' + auth + '"           
   }'
```

You don't need to specify the wildcard, it's default. Also, you don't need to put the `%` inside your query.